# Query on field, not nexted json

Tags: mongodb

Querying syntax. I would like to subset data from a collection where two of the field values are selected.

Some of my attempts are as follows;

```
"{ $and: { "gene" : "A1CF"}, { "tissue" : "LUNG"}}"

Error: Invalid JSON object: { $and: { "gene" : "A1CF"}, { "tissue" : "LUNG"}}

"{ { "gene" : "A1CF"}, { "tissue" : "LUNG"}}"

Error: Invalid JSON object: { { "gene" : "A1CF"}, { "tissue" : "LUNG"}}
```

I am querying on gene and tissue, in this example; A1CF and LUNG.

My JSON object is;

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5d139e3817ddc2d8750e0f13"), 
"gene" : "A1CF", 
"driver_genename" : "ERBB2", 
"target_genename" : "A1CF", 
"wilcox_p" : 0.00777647226632117, 
"effect_size" : 0.772727272727273, 
"zdiff" : -1.0725469683635, 
"tissue" : "BREAST"
```

}

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d139e3817ddc2d8750e0f14"), 
    "gene" : "A1CF", 
    "driver_genename" : "AFF4", 
    "target_genename" : "A1CF", 
    "wilcox_p" : 0.0120300751879699, 
    "effect_size" : 0.907407407407407, 
    "zdiff" : -0.0983195839378545, 
    "tissue" : "LARGE_INTESTINE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$and` MonogoDB operator expects an array i.e.

```
.find({ $and: [{ "gene" : "A1CF"}, { "tissue" : "LUNG"}] });
```

See details at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

**HOWEVER:**

You should just be able to do this, which should have the same outcome:

```
.find({ "gene" : "A1CF", "tissue" : "LUNG" });
```

Comment: Great! If you could accept the answer (the tick on the left of my answer) that will close this question :)